# Spock framework: how can I automatically reset object state after spec is completed

Tags: mocking, state, spock, revert

I've got Spring service `A` which internally uses service `B`.

I want:

1. Mock service `B`
2. Set mocked version into service `A`
3. Test service `A` behavior
4. Set previous version of service `B` to service `A` (reset state)

The problem is last step - I can remember `B` at `setup` and set it in `cleanup` stages. But can I configure to do it automatically (something similar to `@ConfineMetaClassChanges`)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported out-of-the-box, but it could be implemented as a JUnit rule or Spock extension. (`@ConfineMetaClassChanges` is a Spock extension.)